# Generating UIImage from GPUImage video frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I'm trying to generate a `UIImage` from a video frame captured by `GPUImage`. I've done a lot of `AVFoundation` video work, but i'm new to using `GPUImage`. I've `subclassed` `GPUImageVideoCamera` and added this method, but the `UIImage` is always nil. If anyone can tell me where i've gone so horribly wrong, i'd be very appreciative!

```
- (void)processVideoSampleBuffer:( CMSampleBufferRef )sampleBuffer
```

{
    [super processVideoSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];  // to let GPUImage do it's processing first

```
if (!self.thumbnailGenerated)
{
    CMTime timestamp = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer);
    NSLog(@"%f", (float)timestamp.value / timestamp.timescale);

    self.thumbnailGenerated = YES;

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                  {
                      // generate a preview frame from the last filter in the camera filter chain

                      UIImage *thumbnailImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[self.targets lastObject] newCGImageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput]];
                      NSString *pathToMovie = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Thumbnail.png"];
                      [UIImagePNGRepresentation(thumbnailImage) writeToFile:pathToMovie atomically:YES];
                  });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used this code to generate a CGImageRef of the first frame, used for thumbnail

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:videoURl options:nil];
AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [AVAssetImageGenerator assetImageGeneratorWithAsset:asset];
[imageGenerator setAppliesPreferredTrackTransform:YES];
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:asset.URL];
CGImageRef  image = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:kCMTimeZero actualTime:nil error:&error];
```

You can replace `kCMTimeZero` with some actual value to get the frame you'd like.

After that, you'll have to convert your `CGImageRef` to a `UIImage`.

Comment: While this is appreciated, it has a few issues that make it not appropriate for what i'm doing:

1. It operates outside of GPUImage, so it doesn't include GPU filters / processing.
2. Specifying a time causes AVAssetImageGenerator to seek into the AVURLAsset's media from the beginning i.e. specifying a time near the end of a long video would take much longer than specifying a time near the beginning.
3. I've already got the CMSampleBufferRef, and - presumably - GPUImage has already applied the filters with the call to super.

I do appreciate the tip, it's just not what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that is of any help, but I'm getting thumbnail while processing video. For this purpose I'm using

```
 videoInput --> someMyOperations --> fileOutput
 someMyOperations --> imageOutput //imageOutput is PictureOutput()
 videoInput.start() //that needs to be called!
 imageOutput.saveNextFrameToUrl(coverUrl, format: .jpg) { file in
     //here goes the code what to do with thumbnail
     videoInput.cancel() //quite probably here you want this
 }
```

That's guessing - I don't see your code, but for me this works.