# Grab an image from willOutputSampleBuffer or related?

Tags: gpuimage

So, Brad Larson is awesome. I'm using his GPUImage library since he optimized the CGContextCreateImage for video output to instead render straight into OpenGL. Then he rewrote it to be even more amazing, and half the questions are outdated. The other half have the new callbacks, [Like this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222476/generating-uiimage-from-gpuimage-video-frame), but for the life of me, I can't get the video frames callback to not be nil. (the CMSampleBuffer to CIImage functions)

I know I have to "tag the next frame" to be kept in memory, thanks to his blog. I also know I process it (but GPUImageVideo also does that), then I grab from the framebuffer. Still nill.

The capture command that's supposed to auto-filter it into a CGImage, from the CGImagePicture's processImageUpToFilter function seems to be what I want, and I've seen it mentioned, but I am lost as to how to hook up the output to its frameBuffer.

Or should I use GPUImageRawDataOutput, and how to hook up? I've been copying and pasting, editing, experimenting, but unsure if it's just the fact I don't know openGL enough to hook up the right stuff or?

Any help is appreciated. I wouldn't ask, since so many related questions are up here, but I use them and still get nil on the output.

Here is my current try:

```
func willOutputSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!) {
        gpuImageVideoCamera.useNextFrameForImageCapture()
        //Next line seems like a waste, as this func is called in GPUImageVideoCamera already.
        gpuImageVideoCamera.processVideoSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer);
        if let image = gpuImageVideoCamera.imageFromCurrentFramebuffer()
        {
          //it's nil
        }
}
```

Comment: Update: I have this working now, but something is odd. If I turn on the transformFilter's useNextFrameForImageCap it slows the camera down, the preview window gets about 0.2 frames/sec, but it caps the image, in the willOutput call still, with transformFilter.imageFromCurrentFramebuffer. The videoCamera's useNext call, I haven't gotten working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to use the filter instead, and useNextFrame should be AFTER processing to not go super-slow.

Inside of willOutputSampleBuffer, this is it.

```
    if let image = transformFilter.imageFromCurrentFramebuffer()
   {
        // image not nil now.
   }
   transformFilter.useNextFrameForImageCapture(); //enusre this comes after
```

This has given us stunning speeds that beat Google's p2p library. Brad, thanks, everyone should support your efforts.